# Error handling within Javascript function

Tags: javascript

Issue: The issue was that the page crashed if the postcode was not a valid i.e. actual, postcode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>VEMap.Geocode Method</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var map = null;

    function GetMap() {
        map = new VEMap('myMap');
        map.LoadMap();

    }

    function ClickGeocode() {

        map.Geocode(document.getElementById('txtQuery').value, findCallback);
    }

    function findCallback(layer, findResults, placeResults, moreResults, error) {
    var s = '';
    if (placeResults) {
        for (var i = 0; i < placeResults.length; ++i) {
            s += 'Name: ' + placeResults[i].Name + '\n';
            s += 'LatLong: ' + placeResults[i].LatLong + '\n';
            s += 'MatchCode: ' + placeResults[i].MatchCode + '\n';
            s += 'MatchConfidence: ' + placeResults[i].MatchConfidence + '\n';
            s += '\n\n';
        }
    }
    else {
        // Code was an error! 
        // Do something else!
        console.log(error);
    }

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Ok, so how do you know it's invalid?

Comment: Can you provide jsFiddle demo

Comment: If you change the postcode to say "12345XYZ" it throws an error. @MattBurland

Comment: Of course @FUserThrowError http://jsfiddle.net/indofraiser/jh2ge/

Comment: @indofraiser: What throws an error? Where? You need to add enough detail to your question for people to be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at you code and cleaning up your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jh2ge/3/) it looks like you can just check if `placeResults` is null:

```
    function findCallback(layer, findResults, placeResults, moreResults, error) {
        var s = '';
        if (placeResults) {
            for (var i = 0; i < placeResults.length; ++i) {
                s += 'Name: ' + placeResults[i].Name + '\n';
                s += 'LatLong: ' + placeResults[i].LatLong + '\n';
                s += 'MatchCode: ' + placeResults[i].MatchCode + '\n';
                s += 'MatchConfidence: ' + placeResults[i].MatchConfidence + '\n';
                s += '\n\n';
            }
        }
        else {
            // Code was an error! 
            // Do something else!
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If txtQuery is holding the postal code, then try this:

```
var defaultPostalCode = 'xy12345';

function ClickGeocode() {
    var postalCode = document.getElementById('txtQuery').value;
    if (!isValidPostalCode(postalCode, 'US')) {
        postalCode = defaultPostalCode;
    }
    map.Geocode(postalCode, findCallback);
}

function isValidPostalCode(postalCode, countryCode) {
    switch (countryCode) {
        case "US":
            postalCodeRegex = /^([0-9]{5})(?:[-\s]*([0-9]{4}))?$/;
            break;
        case "CA":
            postalCodeRegex = /^([A-Z][0-9][A-Z])\s*([0-9][A-Z][0-9])$/;
            break;
        default:
            postalCodeRegex = /^(?:[A-Z0-9]+([- ]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)?$/;
    }
    return postalCodeRegex.test(postalCode);
}
```

Comment: I think I needed to phrase my query better @DennisT I mean if they postcode is not found rather than not in the correct structure. So lets say "AA1 1AA" is a valid UK postcode but I type in "AA1 2AA" and that does not exist. I want to handle that, ideally put an error message in a label but no action also works i.e. Like a try catch all in .Net